# Running into live server error while trying open my website form Visual Studio (picture attached)

Tags: visual-studio-code, application-error

I want to use live server so i can easily see the changes i make to my website however whenever i try to "go live" an error message pops up and no browser is opened with my website.

I've attached an image of the error but so far have not been able to find any answers from people with the same problem.

I'm fairly new to this so i have no idea how to solve it other than trying to reinstall/restart a few times which didnt work. Any one know what might be causing this message?
Image is the error prompt that pops up, saying application not found

[image: Image is the error prompt that pops up, saying application not found]

Comment: If you can, right click inside your html file and then select the option `Open with live Server` and check?

Comment: Related: [Why is not live server extension is not working in VScode?](/q/59358326/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a browser in the Extension setting

[image: ui settings]

or by adding this setting to you `settings.json` file

```js
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
```

[image: json settings]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the firewall permissions as originally i did not allow liveserver to use private networks. I think that change is what fixed it. Thanks for the input guys!